# Python: how to join named values from JSON to string

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to revive an old Python project of mine, and I am stuck on something I'm sure I knew how to do in the past. Suppose I have this input coming from an API:

```
{'title': 'An awesome title', 'authors': [{'url': 'https://example.com/authors/author1', 'name': 'First Author'}, {'url': 'https://example.com/authors/author2', 'name': 'Second Author'}]}
```

I'm trying to get to this output:

```
Authors: First Author, Second Author
```

We might have only one author, or more than two. Could someone refresh my memory on how to join those values? Thanks!

Comment: what have you tried so far? have you looked into how `dict` works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input you show is not JSON, just a python dict, that contains a list

```
value = {'title': 'An awesome title',
         'authors': [{'url': 'https://example.com/authors/author1', 'name': 'First Author'},
                     {'url': 'https://example.com/authors/author2', 'name': 'Second Author'}]}

names = ", ".join(author['name'] for author in value['authors'])
print("Authors:", names)  # Authors: First Author, Second Author
```

If you have a JSON content, so a `str`, load it before

```
import json

value = '{"title": "An awesome title", "authors": [{"url": "https://example.com/authors/author1", "name": "First Author"}, {"url": "https://example.com/authors/author2", "name": "Second Author"}]}'
value = json.loads(value)
names = ", ".join(author['name'] for author in value['authors'])
print("Authors:", names)  # Authors: First Author, Second Author
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it with `end=''`

```py
l = {'title': 'An awesome title',
    'authors': [{'url': 'https://example.com/authors/author1', 'name': 'First Author'},
                {'url': 'https://example.com/authors/author2', 'name': 'Second Author'}]}

print('Authors:', end=' ')
for e in l['authors']:
    print(e['name'], end=', ')
```